# Show cron jobs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

In a Laravel application, I have set up a lot of cron jobs. Often my colleagues ask me when does this and that job run, and every time I have to dig into the code and find the answer in app/Console/Kernel.php.

It would be nice if it somehow could be visualized on a page somewhere in the application so that they could look it up themselves. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Make log of those cron job

Comment: Using a [cron expression library](https://github.com/dragonmantank/cron-expression), pull the crontab from the user's profile, iterate through each line, and calculate the expression. Should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Laravel puts only 1 line in the crontab, so I think a cron expression library won't work